# Granting access to a user in TFS for a limited time

Tags: tfs, sql-grant

I'm a QA team member and responsible for granting access to developers, there is more than 100 developer and sometimes I forget revoke the access which was granted, it has dire consequences for me! I developed an application to remind me to revoke accesses, but still I'm facing the same problem because there is two other colleagues granting accesses
is there any option in TFS to grant accesses for a limited time?
thank you in advance

Comment: Time limited access to TFS is not a problem I have come across, and is not something TFS offers out of the box, if you want to automate it TFS has a rich API (how you use it depends on the TFS Version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should manage access to TFS via an Active Directory groups. It's easy to manage AD group membership via C# or even via PowerShell, and then all you need to do to revoke access is pull the user out of the AD groups.